# Using CORS to list files on Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, cors

This is probably a dumb question, but I am new to Web programming. I am trying to communicate with the Google Drive using client side JavaScript and CORS. I first used the jsclient library and that worked fine:

```
request = gapi.client.drive.files.list( {'q': " trashed = false " } );
```

Using CORS, my code looks like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET','https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files');

var mysearch = encodeURIComponent("q=trashed=false");

xhr.open('GET',"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?" +mysearch,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
xhr.onload = function() { handleResponse(xhr.responseText); };
xhr.onerror = function() { handleResponse(null); };
xhr.send();
```

I have tried:

```
var mysearch = encodeURIComponent("q=trashed=false");
var mysearch = encodeURIComponent("trashed=false");
var mysearch = encodeURIComponent("q='trashed=false'");
```

They all return the list of all the files. If I don't have a search string, I also get all the files.

I would like to have other search parameters also, using &, but I can't get just one to work. 
How do I format the mysearch string?

Comment: To clarify your question, you are saying that the CORS request works, but that it doesn't handle filtering correctly? Have you tried this:

    var mysearch = encodeURIComponent("trashed=false");
    xhr.open('GET',"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q="+mysearch,true);

Comment: Yes, that fixes the problem. So I need to leave ?q= outside the encoded part. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode only the value part of the parameter:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=' + encodeURIComponent("'trashed=false'")
```